# Extending constants in Golang

Tags: go, constants

Here's my requirement: I have 2 sets of constants. I want to form a third set which is nothing but a union of the above 2 sets. How do I achieve that?

```
type CompOp byte

const (
    EQUAL CompOp = iota
    NOT_EQUAL
)

type LogOp byte

const (
    AND LogOp = iota
    OR
)
```

I want a third set, say Operator

```
type Op {CompOp, LogOp}
```

or

```
var Op = CompOp + LogOp
```

But neither of the above 2 ways work. How do I achieve this requirement?

The above is important to me I'm trying to achieve this :

```
type logExpr struct { 
    expr Expression
    op LogOp 
}  

type compExpr struct { 
    expr Expression
    op CompOp 
} 

type filterExpr struct { 
    expr Expression
    op Op 
}
```

Comment: I have thought about your question, but I'm afraid you are either asking for the impossible (types aren't sets, no sets in Go) or the question isn't clear enough. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CompOp` and `LogOp` are not sets of the same type. They cannot be combined this way. If they could, they would conflict anyway, since both `EQUAL` and `AND` are both 0 (since they're the first `iota` in their blocks). You will need another design.

The most common design would be to combine all the operators into a single `const` block, and then provide functions like `IsCompare()` or `IsLogic()` to distinguish them if that's necessary. See `os.IsExist()` and `os.IsPermission()` as a template.

Here's one way that I might implement it. It wastes a few values for min/max, but it keeps the code very simple to read and easy to update.

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/jH14oETyDr)

```
const (
    // Comparison operators
    minComparison Op = iota
    EQUAL
    NOT_EQUAL
    maxComparison

    // Logic operators
    minLogic
    AND
    OR
    maxLogic
)

func IsComparsion(op Op) bool {
    return op >= minComparison && op <= maxComparison
}

func IsLogic(op Op) bool {
    return op >= minLogic && op <= maxLogic
}
```

---

But can you treat the different kinds of ops as types? Yeah, you can, and maybe it'll work better for you. For example, consider ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/q5x8AjE_mS)):

```
type Op interface {
    isOp()
}

type CompOp byte

const (
    EQUAL CompOp = iota
    NOT_EQUAL
)

func (op CompOp) isOp() {}

type LogOp byte

const (
    AND LogOp = iota
    OR
)

func (op LogOp) isOp() {}

func doOpThingBasedOnValue(op Op) {
    switch op {
    case EQUAL:
        println("passed equal")
    case AND:
        println("passed and")
    }
}

func doOpThingBasedOnType(op Op) {
    switch op.(type) {
    case CompOp:
        println("passed a comp")
    case LogOp:
        println("passed a logic")
    }
}
```

So maybe that's even closer to what you're thinking of. Note that even though both `AND` and `EQUAL` are "0", as an interface, they are distinguishable, so we can switch on them like you'd want. Go is cool that way.

Comment: If you're using `minComparison` and `maxComparision` as actual values, they also increment `iota`, and then you should rather use `<` and `>` only instead of `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: I debated that and went back and forth, since they're technically invalid. I left it as <= in case it were later changed to "minLogic = AND". That way the undefined case could become defined (and the values could be recovered) without creating a subtle bug.

Comment: Then I would rather use `EQUAL Op = iota - 1` and `maxComparison Op = iota - 2`, and `AND Op = iota - 3` and `maxLogic = iota - 4`. It may be less readable but "more" correct.

Comment: Right now, even I have them together as a single set of constants (Op). But with that, when ever I create compExpr or  logExpr, I gotta check for op.IsCompare() and op.IsLogic() respectively. Is there a way where I can declare the type of op in filterExpr as either LogOp or CompOp ??

Comment: @icza `EQUAL Op = iota - 1` , `maxComparison Op = iota - 2` , `AND Op = iota - 3` and `maxLogic = iota - 4` ..  Can yu brief on how would these help ?

Comment: @pritz It's just an alternative definition of `minXXX` and `maxXXX` constants.